# gdb: debug line by line with pipe

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, line-by-line

If I want to debug my program I call it like this:

```
gdb ./myprog
$ run < input.txt
```

But now I want to execute it line by line, but how can I do this? I know the `step` command but I can only call it, if the run command was called before. Do I have to stop the execution directly after the run command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Gdb` has a `start` command, which takes the same arguments as the `run` command. After starting the program, it stops as soon as possible, usually at the start of the `main` function. After that, you can use the `step` command and any other commands that require a live process.

Reference: [Debugging with GDB: Starting your Program](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html)